# Dynamic DatePart when using DateDiff

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff, datepart

Is there a way to pass the DatePart parameter of DateDiff as a variable?
So that I can write code that is similar to this?

```
DECLARE @datePart VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @dateParameter INT

SELECT @datePart = 'dd'
SELECT @dateParameter = 28

SELECT
    *
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(@datePart, MyTable.MyDate, GETDATE()) < @dateParameter
```

The only ways I can think of doing it are with a CASE statement checking the value of the parameter or by building the SQL as a string and running it in an EXEC.

Does anyone have any "better" suggestions? The platform is MS SQL Server 2005

Comment: It's not much better than a case statement but you could use the dreaded dynamic sql

Comment: @Robin Day: I didn't know about this until i read BOL.  Great catch!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to BOL entry on [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794(SQL.90).aspx) (*arguments* section) for SQL Server 2005,

> These dateparts and abbreviations cannot be supplied as a user-declared variable.

So you are probably stuck with Dynamic SQL or using a CASE statement.
But I would opt for a CASE version instead of dynamic SQL.

Comment: Could you please explain why you prefer CASE over dynamic SQL? IMO I prefer dynamic SQL because it is less coding than having to write out a case for every possible datepart.

Answer (score 25):

Old but still valid unfortunately.

I did it the case way and just want to share the code so you don't have to do all the annoying typing I had to do. Covers all possible date parts. Just replace the name of the function and the date function to implement for other T-SQL date functions.

***Copy and paste section***

```
-- SELECT dbo.fn_DateAddFromStringPart('year', 1, GETDATE())
CREATE FUNCTION fn_DateAddFromStringPart
(
    @Interval VARCHAR(11),
    @Increment INT,
    @Date SMALLDATETIME
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @NewDate DATETIME

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SELECT @NewDate = CASE
        WHEN @Interval IN ('year', 'yy', 'yyyy') THEN DATEADD(YEAR, @Increment, @Date)
        WHEN @Interval IN ('quarter', 'qq', 'q') THEN DATEADD(QUARTER, @Increment, @Date)
        WHEN @Interval IN ('month', 'mm', 'm') THEN DATEADD(MONTH, @Increment, @Date)
        WHEN @Interval IN ('dayofyear', 'dy', '') THEN DATEADD(DAYOFYEAR, @Increment, @Date)
        WHEN @Interval IN ('day', 'dd', 'd') THEN DATEADD(DAY, @Increment, @Date)
        WHEN @Interval IN ('week', 'wk', 'ww') THEN DATEADD(WEEK, @Increment, @Date)
        WHEN @Interval IN ('weekday', 'dw', 'w') THEN DATEADD(WEEKDAY, @Increment, @Date)
        WHEN @Interval IN ('hour', 'hh') THEN DATEADD(HOUR, @Increment, @Date)
        WHEN @Interval IN ('minute', 'mi', 'n') THEN DATEADD(MINUTE, @Increment, @Date)
        WHEN @Interval IN ('second', 'ss', 's') THEN DATEADD(SECOND, @Increment, @Date)
        WHEN @Interval IN ('millisecond', 'ms') THEN DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @Increment, @Date)
        WHEN @Interval IN ('microsecond', 'mcs') THEN DATEADD(MICROSECOND, @Increment, @Date)
        WHEN @Interval IN ('nanosecond', 'ns') THEN DATEADD(NANOSECOND, @Increment, @Date)
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @NewDate

END
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you can really do aside from the suggested dynamic sql or case statement is to always do the datediff at a granular DatePart and then upconvert. This isn't fool proof though, you will get an overflow in the function if you try to datediff to granular a part over too large a span e.g. datediff(second, 0, getdate()). But if you just need something like minute parts you should be fine (double check with max date values you care about).

So for example

```
select datediff(minute, 0, getdate())
```

If I want to convert this to hours, days, etc, I can just divide the result by the appropriate amount. It won't take into account leap years etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, the main reason for needing this is that I want to do a proper Month datediff, rather than a 28/30/31 days. I'm actually going back to this route though I think and will just inform the user its last 30/60/90 days rather than actual months.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely using the dynamic query such as this below works very well, I assume you plan on using only abbreviation for @datePart. I would recommend using a minimum of VARCHAR(4) for datepart this will handle such abbreviations as yyyy and mcs. Happy coding:

```
DECLARE @datePart VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @dateParameter INT
DECLARE @SQLTemp varchar(MAX)


SELECT @datePart = 'dd'
SELECT @dateParameter = 28

set  @SQLTemp ='SELECT * FROM MyTable
    WHERE DATEDIFF('+@datePart+', '+MyTable.MyDate+', GETDATE()) < '+@dateParameter

exec (@SQLTemp)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there are better ways then you describe.  Sql Server probably compiles the DATEDIFF query to a set of operations that depend on the datepart parameter.  So you'd need a CASE, or dynamic queries.

Answer (score -1):

I created a Scalar values function to do this. It is based on the solutions mentioned above but easier to implement in your code

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[dynamic_dateadd] 
(
@unit varchar(5),
@number int,
@dt datetime
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    declare @result datetime
    if (@unit='M') BEGIN SET @result=(select DATEADD(M,@number,@dt)) END
    if (@unit='WW') BEGIN SET @result=(select DATEADD(WW,@number,@dt)) END
    if (@unit='D') BEGIN SET @result=(select DATEADD(D,@number,@dt)) END
    if (@unit='H') BEGIN SET @result=(select DATEADD(HH,@number,@dt)) END
    return(@result)
END
```

In a query you can use this function like this:

```
select startdate, validity_unit, validity_number,
dbo.dynamic_dateadd(valididy_unit,validity_number,startdate) as enddate
from SALES_subscription
```