# Defining type as a variable - DATEADD(type, value, date) - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I had to change the date in one of a column of my SQL table (datetime field), increment YEAR by 1. The simple way to perform this action would be (unless someone knows a better way) to update table and SET column with DATEADD()

```
-- sample 1    
-- DATEADD(type, value, date)
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE())
```

Since I'm a lazy programmer, I don't want to keep updating the tables every time we run in to such situation. So I decided to write a small script (function) which gets TYPE, VALUE from the user and perform the operation. But I ran into a situation where I can't use TYPE as a variable.

```
-- Sample 2
-- Error in the code
DECLARE @type VARCHAR(10) = 'YEAR'
        ,@increment INT = 1

SELECT DATEADD(@type, @increment, GETDATE())
```

I can write a case statement where based on the 'TYPE' value I can select the update statement.

```
-- Sample 3
DECLARE @type VARCHAR(10) = 'YEAR'
        ,@increment INT = 1

UPDATE  Table_name
SET     Column_date = CASE @type WHEN 'YEAR' THEN DATEADD(YEAR, @increment, Column_date)
                                WHEN 'MONTH' THEN DATEADD(MONTH, @increment, Column_date)
                                -- and so on
                        END
```

But is there a way to perform the action without the case statement, or can anyone make sample code '2' run?

P.S. Its more of a knowledge based question - Its not holding me back, I'm just curious to know if its possible.

Thanks! :)

Comment: You would have to use dynaic SQL or the `case` statement that you are using.

Comment: You can't use a variable for the datepart argument of `DATEADD` as shown in sample 2. See [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819%28v=sql.110%29.aspx "DATEADD").

Comment: @S.Rojak i have used variables with dateadd with no issues...

Comment: @singhsac - maybe a function would work better? or you wold have a bunch of unions...im sure there are a few ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to already provided solution is to use a dynamic SQL:

**Setup:**

```
-- drop table dbo.DateTest
create table dbo.DateTest
(
    TheDate DATE,
    UpdatedDate DATE
)

TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.DateTest
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.DateTest (TheDate) VALUES ('20150203'), ('20150506'), ('20141231')
GO
```

**Code:**

```
select * from dbo.DateTest

DECLARE @type VARCHAR(8) = 'year'         -- this must be a DATEADD recognizable token
DECLARE @increment INT = 2
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(1000) = N'
    UPDATE dbo.DateTest SET UpdatedDate = DATEADD(' + @type + ', @increment, TheDate)'

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql, N' @increment INT', @increment

select * from dbo.DateTest
```

I wish date part could be provided as parameter, but it does not seem to be [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834971/sql-dynamic-datepart-when-using-datediff).

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Alexei

Answer (score 3):

You could just get all of the type values from the user and just update them all at once.. Just default to 0 the ones they don't want to change

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 0, 
        @Month INT = 0, 
        @Day INT = 0


UPDATE  Table_name
SET     Column_date = DATEADD(YEAR, @Year, DATEADD(Month, @Month, DATEADD(Day, @Day, Column_date)))
```

Comment: Its good but effecting the processing time :(

I'll give a vote up for thinking out of the box