# SQL Server CE: how to save an amound of time?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce-4

I need to save an amount of time (3 days, 1 month, 5 years, etc).

`Datetime` seems to be for saving a date and time (4/5/14 21:03). I could save the number of days as a number, but I will like to be able to save in different units (days, weeks, months...)

Is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Dynamic DatePart when using DateDiff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/834971/5690722)

> So you are probably stuck with Dynamic SQL or using a CASE statement.

Basically, you need to store *datepart* and *number* to apply `DATEADD (datepart , number , date)` to a *date*. Splitting one string on each value might be too resource-consuming, so it might be best to use two separate fields: `char(1)` for  *datepart* and `smallint` (-32,768 to 32,767 should be enough) for *number* to save on storage space.

Without user functions and Dynamic SQL support in SQL Server Compact the only option to implement the logic seems to be through the `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT 
  CASE [datepart]
    WHEN 'y' THEN DATEADD (yy, [number], [date])
    WHEN 'm' THEN DATEADD (mm, [number], [date])
    WHEN 'w' THEN DATEADD (ww, [number], [date])
    ELSE          DATEADD (dd, [number], [date])
  END As [New Date]
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the amount of time in seconds, store in int or bigint