# Using DATEDIFF to assign dynamic interval

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code, which works as expected.

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime2 = '2007-05-05';  
DECLARE @enddate datetime2 = '2007-05-04';  
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, @startdate, @enddate);
```

I now want to be able to use a variable to switch from "year, week, days, etc. So I tried this, but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime2 = '2007-05-05';  
DECLARE @enddate datetime2 = '2007-05-04';  
DECLARE @interval varchar = 'year'
SELECT DATEDIFF(@interval, @startdate, @enddate);
```

I get:
Msg 1023, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
Invalid parameter 1 specified for datediff.

Thank you,

Raul Gonzalez

Comment: You can't pass a parameter to the interval. You would have to use dynamic sql for this. Or perhaps rethinking slightly what you are trying to do.

Comment: `year` in SQL is a *language keyword*, similar to SELECT and DECLARE. That is why you can't replace it with a variable. Dynamic SQL is the only way to make it work in a variable way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Dynamic DatePart when using DateDiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834971/sql-dynamic-datepart-when-using-datediff)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use dynamic sql for this. Once you start using dynamic sql you open yourself up to sql injection. Here is how you can do this and protect yourself against sql injection. The case expression may seem a little odd but if you have a value in your @interval that is not allowed the entire sql string will be NULL and no harm will come to your database. Also, please notice that you did not specify a length for @interval. For variables the default length is 1 so it would only be 'y' not 'year' as you expected it to be. Always specify the scale and precision of variables.

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime2 = '2007-05-05';  
DECLARE @enddate datetime2 = '2007-05-04';  
DECLARE @interval varchar(10) = 'year'

declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @SQL = 'select datediff(' + 
    case @interval when 'year' then 'year'
        when 'week' then 'week'
        when 'days' then 'day'
    end
    + ', @startdate, @enddate)'

exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@startdate datetime2, @enddate datetime2', @startdate, @enddate
```

Comment: Thanks Sean. That seems to do the trick for what I wanted to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it dynamically:

```
declare @datediff varchar(max)
set @datediff = 'SELECT DATEDIFF(' + @interval + ',' + '''' + cast(@startdate as varchar(10)) + '''' + ',' + '''' + cast(@enddate as varchar(10)) + '''' + ')'
exec (@datediff)
```

Comment: You are missing some additional single quotes around your dates. But I would prefer to use sp_executesql and paramterize the dates.

Comment: With the example by Sam above I'm getting.

 "The data types varchar and datetime2 are incompatible in the add operator."

Comment: thats because you need to convert those values to varchar. See edits

Answer (score 0):

Now let's say that I have the following:

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime2 = '2017-11-03';  
DECLARE @enddate datetime2 = '2018-11-03';  
DECLARE @interval varchar(10) = 'month'

declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @SQL = 'select datediff(' + 
    case @interval 
        when 'year' then 'year'
        when 'month' then 'month'
        when 'week' then 'week'
        when 'day' then 'day'
    end
    + ', @startdate, @enddate)'

exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@startdate datetime2, @enddate datetime2', 
@startdate, @enddate
```

The result is "12"

Now I'd like to have 12 values displayed as:

2017/11/03

2017/12/03

2018/01/03

2018/02/03

2018/03/03

2018/04/03

2018/05/03

2018/06/03

2018/07/03

2018/08/03

2018/09/03

2018/10/03

Comment: Are you saying want to get a date output for each date interval within the selected range? So if you had those two dates and choose month you would get 12. If the interval was day you would get 365 and week would return 52? To be honest I would probably open this as a new question. The complexity changes significantly from your original question.

Comment: Thanks Sean,

This is what I got so far, but you're right. It took me a while to incorporate it with your solution.

SELECT  DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)) AS MonthName
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x
WHERE   x.type = 'p'        
AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate);